# ¿Por qué me da este error al ejecutar la siguiente consulta en access y no en otros gestores de bases de datos?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Estoy intentando realizar un informe en Access 2003, y para ello necesito que la siguiente consulta sql me muestre lo necesario:

```
SELECT TBJAESTTIT.TITPRIMA2327CRIGAS,
    TBJAESTTIT.ESTANO,
    TBJAESTTIT.EXPCOD,
    TBJAESTTIT.CENCOD,
    TBJAESTTIT.THCOD,
    TBJAESTGASTOS.ESTANO,
    TBJAESTGASTOS.THCOD,
    TBJAESTGASTOS.OCACOD,
    TBJAESTGASTOS.CENCOD,
    TBJAESTGASTOS.EXPCOD,
    TBJAESTGASTOS.GASCOD,
    TBJAGASTOS.GASDES_E & ' / ' + Chr(13) + Chr(10) & TBJAGASTOS.GASDES_C AS GASDES,
    TBJAESTGASTOS.EGIMPORTEAPRO
FROM TBJAESTGASTOS
INNER JOIN TBJAGASTOS ON (TBJAESTGASTOS.ESTANO = TBJAGASTOS.GASCAMPANA)
    AND (TBJAESTGASTOS.GASCOD = TBJAGASTOS.GASCOD)
INNER JOIN TBJAESTTIT ON (TBJAESTTIT.ESTANO = TBJAESTGASTOS.ESTANO)
    AND (TBJAESTTIT.CENCOD = TBJAESTGASTOS.CENCOD)
    AND (TBJAESTTIT.EXPCOD = TBJAESTGASTOS.EXPCOD)
    AND (TBJAESTTIT.THCOD = TBJAESTGASTOS.THCOD)
WHERE TBJAESTGASTOS.ESTANO >= '2023';
```

En los gestores de datos en los que estoy trabajando (MariaDB, DBeaver), la consulta no me produce ningún error, y me muestra los campos necesarios para el informe. En cambio, cuando la realizo en Access 2003, siempre me aparece lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He estado revisando el código bastante tiempo, y la verdad es que no encuentro el motivo de este fallo. ¿Hay alguien sabe si Access tiene alguna particularidad en cuanto a escribir sql? ¿Por qué me va bien en otras plataformas y en Access 2003 no?

Gracias de antemano. Un cordial saludo

Comment: El error que te está dando, puede ser porque en Access para saber que son Tablas y Columnas, estos suelen estar delimitados por []. Podrías probar a escribir tal cual la tienes, pero entre corchetes. Ej:  SELECT [TBJAESTTIT].[TITPRIMA2327CRIGAS], [TBJAESTTIT].[ESTANO] .....

Comment: Gracias. Ahora voy a probar. Un saludo

Comment: Veo otro tema.. estas mezclando & y + para concatenar... primero que todo, dbeaver es para conectarte a una base de datos.. supongo lo estas probando en Maria, que es mysql y la sintaxis no es la misma. por eso te da error.. tene en cuenta que no es exactamente el mismo SQL para todas las bases...

Comment: Por favor, publica el mensaje de error como texto y no como imagen. Los diálogos de error soportan copiar, para que puedas pegar acá el mensaje.

Comment: También, viendo el mensaje de error, la consulta no parece la misma, pues el mensaje incluye una literal `A`, al final del código, que no aparece en la consulta que publicas. Asegúrate de publicar la misma consulta que produce el error.

Comment: Hola jachguate. Gracias por los consejos. Pero esa A que se observa al final es la correspondiente al AND que viene después. Un saludo

Answer (score 2):

El problema consistía en como Access 2003 trata a los inner join. Cada inner join debe ir entre paréntesis, y si hay varios, agruparlos con paréntesis. Por ejemplo, sería algo como:

```
FROM ((TBJAESTGASTOS INNER JOIN TBJAGASTOS ON (TBJAESTGASTOS.GASCOD = TBJAGASTOS.GASCOD) AND (TBJAESTGASTOS.ESTANO = TBJAGASTOS.GASCAMPANA)) INNER JOIN TBJAESTTIT ON (TBJAESTGASTOS.ESTANO = TBJAESTTIT.ESTANO) AND (TBJAESTGASTOS.THCOD = TBJAESTTIT.THCOD) AND (TBJAESTGASTOS.OCACOD = TBJAESTTIT.OCACOD) AND (TBJAESTGASTOS.EXPCOD = TBJAESTTIT.EXPCOD))
```

Gracias por vuestras aportaciones y ayuda